# How to retrive all state name by javascript from state.xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml, foreach

## javascript

```
<states>
<state name="Rajkot" colour="#ff0000"> 
 <point lat="23.463246" lng="68.444284"/>
 <point lat="23.986253" lng="68.708496"/>
</state>
<state name="Surat" colour="#ff0000"> 
 <point lat="23.463246" lng="68.444284"/>
 <point lat="23.986253" lng="68.708496"/>
</state> 
<state name="Baroda" colour="#ff0000"> 
 <point lat="23.463246" lng="68.444284"/>
 <point lat="23.986253" lng="68.708496"/>
</state>
```

I have this xml file called state.xml. I want each state name(baroda,surat,rajkot) and after that each points of each state name's using loop by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/ynKEk/

With jquery you can parse an xml string to an object like this:

```
var $xml = $(xmlString);
```

After that, you can traverse this object like this:

```
$xml.find('state').each(function() {

    var state = {};
    state.name = $(this).attr('name');

}
```

Comment: Well, this is Javascript and jQuery is a javascript library. Anyway it can be done using directly an XML Parser this way: http://jsfiddle.net/vLxpq/ You can check this page to see how to get an xml parser from the browser: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp